# Custom Font is not shown in output

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a question. I want to use a custom font, got the .woff, .woff2, .eot, .ttf, .svg and so on. All these files are in a folder called 'fonts'.

I tried accessing them over @font-face but the font is not shown on the site. So I tried it on an empty page, so that no bootstrap css or anything else is interfering, but the problem is still not solved.

This is my css

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Bauhaus93'
src: 
      url('/fonts/BAUHS93.woff') 
           format('woff'), 

      url('/fonts/BAUHS93.woff2') 
           format('truetype');

}
```

and this is my html where I also put a Google web font in to check if hosted fonts will be ignored as well.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat'   rel='stylesheet'>

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <p style="font-family: 'Montserrat'">TEST text test </p>
    <p style="font-family: 'Bauhaus93'">TEST text test </p>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fonts are located in the same subfolder, remove the `/` at the start of your `url()`.

If your fonts folder is in not located in a subfolder, you need to `../` instead of just `/` at the front of your `url()`. Each `../` moves back by 1 folder so you can locate your fonts folder in this way.

For example:

```
url('../fonts/BAUHS93.woff') format('truetype');
```

Comment: Could you tell me the path of the folder? Thanks.

Comment: Ok I think I might know why your fonts aren't appearing. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: the path is OriginalFolder/fonts/BAUHS93.woff; the html is in OriginalFolder/test.html; the css is in OriginalFolder/css/style.css

Comment: Ok, the edited solution should work, tell me if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have used wrong syntax there. You should remove the forward slash. `/` is used when your font is located in the fonts folder at the root of the current web.

Ok, I didn't see the file path you provided in the comments. I'll edit my answer. The file paths:
Folder/fonts/BAUHS93.woff; Folder/test.html; Folder/css/style.css;

This syntax is wrong-

```
url('/fonts/BAUHS93.woff')
```

Change it to this-

```
url('../fonts/BAUHS93.woff')
```

This should be used when the file is located in the folder one level up from the current folder

Alternatively, you can link the fonts in the HTML-

```
<link href="fonts/BAUHS93.woff" rel="stylesheet">
```

and simply use `font-family: 'Bauhaus93';` in the css

But you say even this doesn't work. If it doesn't, you should check the names and paths or you can try linking web fonts. Your file could have some error or you could be using a different name than the one defined in the font file.

I also see that you have linked Montserrat in your HTML file and that font should have worked. If even the web font doesn't, you should try adding a semicolon in the style tag- `style="font-family: 'Montserrat';"`, even though it shouldn't make a difference as css usually ignores the absence of semicolons.

Comment: the web font works, I did put it in to see if maybe all css rules are overwritten somehow. I have double checked the paths and names. Since it didn't work in my actual file, I created a new file especially to see if that font works. The .ttf and .svg looks fine to me.

Comment: So the web font didn't work in your actual file but it works in a new file? Strange. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: And could you send a link to your custom font (like, upload it somewhere)? I just wanted to look into it.